# Mysql stored procedure if (select....) > variable then

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to do something like:

```
if ((select count(id) from abc where ...) > variableINT) then .....
```

Why does this doesn´t work properly?

Comment: I want to do something only if count (id) from table abc is higher then number in INT variable. Standard condition, why this make no sense?

Comment: got it now. Well - you need to use `SELECT ... INTO` syntax

Comment: Yes, I need one more variable, I know it yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following in your stored procedure (I assume you basic knowledge of declaring variables and writing queries) :

Declare a variable count_id : `count_id NUMBER;`

Then run your query : `select count(id) into count_id from abc where ...`

Then you can test that variable : `if (count_id > ...) then .... end if`

Comment: That´s it. I have to declare one more variable and can´t select in condition. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a link table (mylinks) with links from source_id to target_id and you want to find only the targets that have more than 5 links. This will work in MySQL. Not sure about MS-SQL though.

select target_id, count(source_id) as num_links from mylinks group by target_id having num_links>5;

Comment: Yes, it will work, but there is no fit to my situation - I have my condition in a complicated while statement - but I didn´t mention it. Thanks you anyway for your answer.